# How to design large nosql with nested data?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, data-modeling

Let's say I want to describe people. I maybe have 1 million persons in my database.
A person has these properties:

```
First name
Last name
Year of birth
Country of birth
City of birth
Country of residence
City of residence
```

Having this, lets add some data:

```
{'David', 'Beckham', 1977, 'UK', 'London', 'USA', 'Los Angeles'}    
{'Lionel', 'Messi', 1987, 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires', 'Spain', 'Barcelona'}
{'Cristiano', 'Ronaldo', 1985, 'Portugal', 'Lisbona', 'Italy', 'Turin'}
```

Now lets say we want to change the name of 'Los Angeles' with 'LA'.
With so many entries, maybe there are 20 000 person that have Los Angeles as city of birth or residence.
What is the best practice in mongodb or generally in nosql? In rdbms you would have a table with cities.
When Los Angeles changes to 'LA' you just change in that table. With my structure above, with all the fields in the same table or document, I would need to go through all the entries. Is that the usual way to do it?

Comment: You are thinking about [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/index.html) operation with the query condition on the field `City`. Having an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/index.html) on the query field helps in terms of efficiency.

Comment: So you're basically saying, having a schema like the one above, with only one "table" with all the fields in it, is the way to go? Provided the City-field has been indexed?

Comment: Take a look at this: [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/index.html). Based upon your use case and application requirements, you have to consider your design.